# photos being not placed perfectly

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem placing the laptop image over the yellow vector thing. I tried doing flexbox too, but everything goes out of place if I try to move the laptop there. Can someone help me place the laptop on that yellow thing and the header text in baseline with laptop. 
as you can see in the photo, laptop photo is below where i wanted, i want it to be little above, the `work faster and harder to achieve your goal` line to be little below in the middle and the logo is also not placed perfectly. I want the design text to get out of the yellow circle

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Circular Std, sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #2B9Dff;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav {
  line-height: 150px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #202427;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

nav a:first-child {
  float: left;
}

nav a:second-child {
  padding-left: 20px
}

nav a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav a span {
  background-color: #2b9dff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

header {
  height: 1000px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background-image: url(images/eclipse1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: bottom right;
}

header h1 {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
}

header img {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href=""><img src="./images/ex.png" alt="" style="height: 52px; width: 58px;" /></a>
      <a href="#">Design</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Work faster and harder to achieve your goals</h1>
    <p>hello I waant this tagline</p>
    <img src="./images/laptop.png" width="750px" height="500px" alt="" />
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

this is what I want

[image]

this is what I'm getting right now

[image]

Comment: Work fater? Is that a spelling mistake or.. Im I missing something aha!? Also: I think this current design looks dope! - Very creative. But regarding your original question, hope someone can direct you the right way.

Comment: yeah that's a spelling mistake. not sure if sarcasm or serious but thanks anyway :)

Comment: You are showing what you want, but not what you are getting as a result.  Can you do that as well?  Also, remove all of the CSS that isn't relevant to what is shown on the screen (the nav stuff, for example).  That will help distill the problem into the root problem.

Comment: the photo is not what i want. the photo is what I'm getting. In the photo, you can see that the laptop is way below. I want it to be a little above that. also the `work faster` line to be in the same line as with the laptop

Comment: did you try using `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to achieve those goals

Comment: yeah I did.. I added position: relative to the header. then position: absolute to the header img{} but the logo in the top left position changes too.. not sure how I go about doing it

Comment: @reduxHelpPlz I love it - it's unique. When you get the amended code - I'd like to see the comparison.

Comment: okay thanks. I added the image of what I want the final design should look like. It's simple though, not very fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sure that `position: relative` and `position absolute` can help you. The reason is you cannot use `header img selector` because there are 2 img tag in the header. Thats why you were saying the logo in the top left position changes too. Instead, you give each img an **id** . See in the HTML here where I assign each **img** an **id**

```
 <header>
    <nav>
      <a href=""><img id="logo" src="./images/ex.png" alt="" style="height: 52px; width: 58px;" /></a>
      <a href="#">Design</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Work faster and harder to achieve your goals</h1>
    <p>hello I waant this tagline</p>
    <img id="laptop" src="./images/laptop.png" width="750px" height="500px" alt="" />
  </header>
```

CSS

```
header {
 position: relative
}

#laptop{
 position: absolute:
 top: 300px;   // you need to config this number to go to the position you want
 right: 300px; // you need to config this number to go to the position you want

}
```

You can do the same with your text

```
<h1 id="work">Work faster and harder to achieve your goals</h1>
<p id="hello">hello I waant this tagline</p>

#work{
 position: absolute:
 top: 300px;   // you need to config this number to go to the position you want
 left: 300px; // you need to config this number to go to the position you want

}
#hello{
 position: absolute:
 top: 400px;   // you need to config this number to go to the position you want
 left: 300px; // you need to config this number to go to the position you want

}
```

The last thing is your Design text to move out of the logo, same thing, add an id

```
  <a href="#" id="design">Design</a>
```

CSS

```
#design {
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;  // you need to config this number to go to the position you want
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. actually the thing was that I didn't notice there were two images in the header. I thought i declared nav outside of the header tag, which is why the logo was also moving alongwith the laptop photo. That's why I was thinking as to why position: absolute and relative wasn't working.